# Should I just quit? I honestly believe this the best question I asked here and its still downvoted?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange post: [Generating n^2 x n^2 valid and pre-solved Sudoku's in $O(n^3)$ time is inconsequential?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/44048/generating-n2-x-n2-valid-and-pre-solved-sudokus-in-on3-time-is-inconsequ)

Should I quit this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to you, really. It looks like you got some helpful comments from @mhum so maybe be satisfied with those.

Comment: Well, I was considering showing that this algorithm solves any $n$-size special cases of the 3-coloring problem. And it can also generate k-coloring "Puzzles" in poly-time. Sorta like Sudoku. Every Sudoku Puzzle of any $n^2 x n^2$ size; when its top $n x n$ box is validly solved. Its remaining squares can be solved under constraint in poly-time. Because, ALL valid Sudoku solutions follow their own cyclic permutation pattern. Which can be used to generate a $O(n^k)$ time grid generator. Update: *It can generate easy instances of k-coloring, but it hasn't been hard-coded yet. Just for Sudoku.*

Comment: May be trivial, but should have sparked interest on this stack. :(